# How to convert a child class into a parent class for saving in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance

I have the following classes called:

```
public class Parent
{
     public string Field1;
     public string Field2; 
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Field3;
}
```

I now have a list of Child objects and I need to pass then into a function that is looking for a Parent class.

What is the best way to convert Child class back to the Parent class (I don't care about field3 at this point)?

I am using NHibernate and when I pass in the child class and try to save it, I get this error:

> No persister for: ChildClass

even though the 'Parent' class has a persister.

Comment: The instances of `Child` *are also* instances of `Parent`.  You should be able to pass them directly, without any modification.  If you cannot, please show the compiler error and the code that causes it.

Comment: @cdhowie - i need to do an explicit conversion because I am using nhibernate and it requires the object be the parent class .

Comment: Added explicit conversion example and link to MSDN for you.

Answer (score 9):

Instances of the child class *are* instances of the parent class.
You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: it would be useful to include a note about covariance, seeing as the OP is talking about a list of children, rather than just a child.

Comment: but in nhibernate, you need to specify the type you want to save to